# What options can be passed to IOService::Terminate in DriverKit

Tags: macos, iokit, driverkit, macos-system-extension

[`virtual kern_return_t IOService::Terminate(uint64_t options)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3538742-terminate) says you can pass a parameter with options. I wonder what the different options are? The documentation does not say anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IOService.iig` file from the XNU source code bundle (7195.50.7.100.1, macOS 11.0.1) contains the following:

```
    /*!
     * @brief       Start an IOService termination.
     * @discussion  An IOService object created with Create() may be removed by calling Terminate().
     *              The termination is asynchronous and will later call Stop() on the service.
     * @param       options No options are currently defined, pass zero.
     * @return      kIOReturnSuccess on success. See IOReturn.h for error codes.
     */
    virtual kern_return_t
    Terminate(
        uint64_t             options);
```

> **options** *No options are currently defined, pass zero.*

On the kernel side, `IOService::terminate` does have a few valid options. I do not know if you can pass these through from DriverKit, however. They might be filtered:

- `kIOServiceSynchronous`:

> *`kIOServiceSynchronous` may be passed to cause `terminate` to not return until the service is finalized.*

- `kIOServiceRequired`:

> *By default, if any client has the service open, `terminate` fails. If the `kIOServiceRequired` flag is passed however, `terminate` will be
> successful though further progress in the destruction of the
> `IOService` object will not proceed until the last client has closed
> it.*

- `kIOServiceTerminateWithRematch`: I'm not quite clear on this one, it's not documented, but a cursory reading of the relevant code suggests that when an object is terminated this way, its provider will re-trigger I/O Kit matching.

There are a few more such as `kIOServiceRecursing` which are used internally when forwarding from `terminate()` itself to the various termination phase functions to keep track of termination status. These should normally not be used from kext code, and I very much doubt that they will be passed through if you use them from DriverKit.